# Using list of LM estimates as stargazer input

Tags: r, list, lm, stargazer

I'm trying to use `stargazer` over a several LM estimates at once, say "OLS1",...,"OLS5".
I would usually insert them as separate arguments at the beginning of the stargazer input. What I'm looking for is a way to input them all with a list that contains them all, being one argument. Something like

```
stargazer(list,...)
```

stargazer arguments explanation states that

> one or more model objects (for regression analysis tables) or data frames/vectors/matrices (for summary statistics, or direct output of content). They can also be included as lists (or even lists within lists).

I was wondering what is the correct way to gather LM estimates in a list so that this would work. When I just save the results in a list I get the following error

```
Error in list.of.objects[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I will mention that I create the elements storing the estimate using `assign`. E.G:

```
assign(some_string,lm(...))
```

So what I have is a string, called some_string, and I want to put the LM result names some_string inside a list. Using `get` doesn't help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I think you want `mget`

```
library(stargazer)

Y <- rnorm(100)
X <- rnorm(100)

assign("string_1", lm(Y ~ X))
assign("string_2", lm(Y ~ X))

my_list <- mget(x = c("string_1", "string_2"))

stargazer(my_list)
```

works for me?

```
library(stargazer)

Y <- rnorm(100)
X <- rnorm(100)
fit_1 <- lm(Y ~ X)
fit_2 <- lm(Y ~ X) 

stargazer(list(fit_1, fit_2))
```

did you name your list `list`? maybe it's grabbing the function?

Comment: I use `assign`  to create "fit_1", "fit_2", etc (I estimate lots of them one after the other). So I can't just create a list mentioning explicitly the element name. What I have is a string with the estimate's name, but `get` doesn't seem to help here, when putting in a list

Comment: hm.  Can you update to include a MWE that creates a list of fits that reproduces your error?

Comment: Thanks! Your `mget` suggestion solved this out for me!